# Azure Managed Domain does not allow any 'management '?

Tags: azure, entra-id, entra-domain-services

Ive recently subscribed to azure Ad domain services, created a vm and joined it to the managed domain.

As i login as the owner , i find all user attributes greyed out and it doesnt allow me to move any users to an OU i create.

I understand there are limits to how much i can administer but is this part of the limitation ?

**What im trying to achieve :** Create a LDAP path to an OU with specific users in Azure Managed Domain.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD DS works in the opposite way you expect. In this scenario, Azure AD is the source of users and they are replicated into Azure AD DS, so any users you create from Azure AD need to be managed through Azure AD, not Azure AD DS and they need to be in the AADDCUsers OU.

You can create users in AAD DS directly and they can sit in any OU, but these users are not available in Azure AD.